# How to create UITableview first index cell show on half banner view using Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, storyboard

My scenario, I am trying to create `UITableview` with `card effects` and top banner. I have added It will work like `stretchable` tableview `header`. Everything I am done by using `storyboard` but I am stuck in showing `half` of `tableview` first `index cell` show on `banner` head. I tried `multiple` ideas but I didn’t completed. Provide some idea for achieve this `design`.

Current Output:

[image: Current output screen]

Expected Output:

[image: Expected output screen]

Comment: you can use tableview `contentInset` and `contentOffSet` to adjust your position

Comment: Maybe try let the header clipToBounds = false to make it display outside it's frame

Comment: I tried but it is not working @karthik

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From your demo project [HERE](https://github.com/tungnguyentp/StretchableTableViewHeader-Swift-master-2) I have made some changes to you existing code like your `scrollViewDidScroll` will be:

```
var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
    self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
}


func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        //Up
        let y = 220 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 220)
        let height = min(max(y, 60), 220)
        if height >= 128 {
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height + 70)
        }
    } else if self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
        //Down
        let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
        let height = min(max(y, 60), 400)
        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height + 80)
    }
}
```

With above code I have added different conditions for up and down as per your requirement and from storyboard I have change top constraint to `84` so that your table will not scroll to top.

[image]

So your full code will look like:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

    let imageView = UIImageView()
    var lastContentOffset: CGFloat = 0

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 50
        tableView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsetsMake(220, 0, 0, 0)
        tableView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray


        imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: 300)
        imageView.image = UIImage.init(named: "poster")
        imageView.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill
        imageView.clipsToBounds = true
        view.addSubview(imageView)
        self.tableView.backgroundColor = .clear
        self.view.bringSubview(toFront: tableView)
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }
}


extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 20
    }
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "customCell", for: indexPath) as! CustomTableViewCell
        switch indexPath.row % 2 {
        case 0:
            cell.titleLabel.text = "Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text ."
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        default:
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.black
            cell.titleLabel.text = "There is no one who loves pain itself, who seeks after it and wants to have it, simply because it is pain..."
            cell.titleLabel.textColor = .white
        }
        return cell
    }

    func scrollViewWillBeginDragging(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {
        self.lastContentOffset = scrollView.contentOffset.y
    }


    func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

        if self.lastContentOffset < scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            let y = 220 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 220)
            let height = min(max(y, 60), 220)
            if height >= 128 {
                imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height + 70)
            }
        } else if self.lastContentOffset > scrollView.contentOffset.y {
            let y = 300 - (scrollView.contentOffset.y + 300)
            let height = min(max(y, 60), 400)
            imageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: UIScreen.main.bounds.size.width, height: height + 80)
        }
    }
}
```

And result will be:

[image]

[HERE](http://s000.tinyupload.com/index.php?file_id=12242887893805347262) is the link for your updated project.

Comment: Awesome help. Thanks buddy. iOS Master @Dharmesh Kheni

Comment: Happy to help you.. :)